# Live Agent: Custom Chat Page not Working

Tags: liveagent, chat, pre-chat

I have a pre chat page that is working fine, but when I assign the custom chat page (got the code sample from Salesforce) to the button, it stops working. The pre chat form page gets reloaded and I lose all the values I type into it.

Do I have to call the custom chat visualforce page from my pre-chat visualforce page or vice-versa?